# How to parse a div content with Flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web-scraping

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<td title="Gardien" class="zentriert rueckennummer bg_Torwart">
  <div class="rn_nummer">30</div>
</td>
```

I want to get the content of the div tag (which is 30 here) using Dart & Flutter...

I tested the following code:

```
List<String> numeros = [];

final numeross = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
numeros = numeross.map
 ((e) => e.getElementsByClassName("rn_nummer")[0].innerHtml).toList();
```

But, I always got an error

> E/flutter ( 6923): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

I searched a lot but in vain...
Any suggestion? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this and here I am using [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package

```
  var document = parse("""
    <td title="Gardien" class="zentriert rueckennummer bg_Torwart">
        <div class="rn_nummer">30</div>
        <div class="rn_nummer">30</div>
        <div class="rn_nummer">30</div>
     </td>
  """);



  //declaring a list of String to hold all the data.
  List<String> data = document.getElementsByClassName("rn_nummer").map((e) => e.innerHtml).toList();

 print(data);
```

output: [30,30,30]